# Is this a proper way to solve fractions?

Tags: fractions

I'm doing Trades Math and as you can imagine it's bit confusing.

Let's say I'm trying to solve for the below question.

```
22' - 5 3/16"
10' - 1 1/2"
13' - 4 9/16"
+ __________
```

so here is what we get

```
v  -  v

45' - 10
```

ok then we now we work with **1/2**. So with "x" it by 8 and get **8/16** now that we have that let's move on.

**3/16 + 8/16 + 9/16 = 20/16** now we can't use **20/16** because it's irregular fraction so lets do **20 - 16 = 4** which is written as

> 16/16 + 4/16
>   = 4/16 or >>> **1 1/4**

So the solution is

```
45' - 11 1/4'
```

This is where I'm confused since 16/16 give us 1 do I actually write it as 1 1/4 and then add that to the 10 making it **11 1/4** or does it stay as **10 1/4'** ?

Comment: Your stated solution `45' - 11 1/4"` is correct (although you changed a double quote to a single quote).  I don't understand what you're confused about.  Possibly it would help if you backed up to the section of your book dealing with improper fractions.

Comment: I was wondering if you add that 1 a/b. Trust me trades math is confusing for example 40' - 14 11/16" is actually supposed to be 41' - 2 11/16" because the 14" is same as 1ft 2in, so we add the 1ft to 40' and then the 2" are left alone making 2 11/16"

Comment: Um not really. I did not make that up, the **40' - 14 11/16" becoming 41' - 2 11/16"** is the answer the teacher provided on the board. You have to watch for your ft and inches as I mentioned this is not regular math but Trades Math.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize you're using the hyphen to indicate two parts of a figure *added* together, rather than subtraction.  In which case, yes, it's pretty obviously 41 feet and 2 11/16 inches.

Comment: 20/16 is a perfectly good number. There's no reason you can't use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right: it is 45' - 11 1/4".

You have 45 feet +  10 inches + 20/16 inches.

20/16 inches is 1 and 1/4 inches, so you have 45 feet + 10 inches + 1 inch + 1/4 inch.

The 1 inch adds in with the 10 and you get 45 feet + 11 inches + 1/4 inch.

Comment: Just wondering because this what I was told. So let's say our answer is `40' - 14 11/16"` because 14 is same as 1ft, 2in then the solution answer must be `41' - 2 11/16"`

Comment: @0111010001110000 If that were your answer, I'd agree. You should carry anything with more than 12 inches over to the feet. However, in your problem you wind up with 11 1/4 inches, which is less than 12 inches.

Comment: So one more quick question. So let's say my solution was `45' - 12 1/4"` would that mean my solution would look like this `46' - 1/4"` or would it be 1 1/4" ? as 12 inches is spot on 1ft.

Comment: @0111010001110000 It would be $46' - 1/4".$ Try writing it out in english. You have 45 feet + 12 inches + 1/4 inch. 12 inches is 1 foot so you have 45 feet + 1 foot + 1/4 inch = 46 feet + 1/4 inch.

Comment: thank you, your awesome :)